Paver patio below yard grade
I’m running into a challenge as I’m building my paver patio and hope I can find some guidance. My issue is that I’ve done the excavation and made sure to have a consistent slope of 1/8 inch every foot starting from the house and because of that I’ve discovered the furthest point of my patio will be below the top of the dirt. I can’t make the patio start any higher so it seems my lawn was not graded correctly.
I was originally thinking of finishing the job and then grading my lawn but then realizing if I lower my lawn to be level with the patio it will make my yard lower than everything around it. I believe this will likely make all water flow towards my yard from the park behind my house and my neighbors yards.
My question is, would a retaining wall be a good solution here around the outer square of my patio? This would allow me to not need to lower my yard grade because I haven’t had any water issues and I don’t want to create issues by lowering the grade of my grass. Any suggestions help.
Thanks


What is the source of your requirement that the slope is a constant 1/8" per foot?  Unless it's a severe undulating area, I'd suggest that you modify your requirement to match the level of the yard and if the patio slopes a tiny bit more, it probably won't make a difference, and no one will notice either.

There isn’t necessarily a requirement to slope 1/8” per foot but the patio starts along my house and I want the water to flow away. Would it be logical to slope out away from the house 10 ft then level it off the rest of the way?

Grading away from the house for 10-12 feet is generally adequate. Carrying that grade for infinite distance tends to run into the impractical pretty quickly.

Yeah, as long as you can grade enough of the pavers to be 10' away, and as long as you have positive drainage to someplace else away from the house, it should be OK.  Like, you could have a dip in your patio in the X direction as long as the dip can drain off the patio in the Y direction, if that makes sense.
